# Как массового обновить записи в таблице по нескольким условиям?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица

[image]

Как массово обновить `status` на 0 в тех строках, где

- значение mad_id = 1 и
- значение mid_id = 2

или

- значение mad_id = 2 и
- значение mid_id = 1

или ....

- значение mad_id = n и
- значение mid_id = k

мне удалось найти только обновление по одному условию.

Comment: то есть где айди mad_id != mid_id? Вот вам и условие, ежели так.

Comment: @Miron, нет, где выполняется или одна группа условий или вторая или n-ная группа условий.
То есть обновить статус, когда в столбах или такая комбинация или другая или третья.

Comment: А есть какая-то система? Или какие-то абсолютно рандомные пары могут быть? Если это так, то ничего не поделаешь - придется все в ручную в запросе писать.

Comment: @Miron `or where or wrere or where...`?

Comment: `where условие1 or условие2 or условие3...` Я бы на вашем месте все же попробовал поискать хоть какую-то систему.

Comment: Значит это и есть решение: `WHERE (mad_id=1 AND mid_id=2) OR (mad_id=2 AND mid_id=1) OR....`. Теперь составить такую строку условия и поместить в запрос. Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше в такой форме: `WHERE (mad_id,mid_id) IN ((1,2), (2,1), ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE таблица SET status=0 WHERE (mad_id=1 AND mid_id=2) OR (mad_id=2 AND mid_id=1) OR (mad_id=n AND mid_id=k)
```